# I cannot see the pagination in /wp-admin posts page

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I am failing to see the pagination to view more posts in the /wp-admin posts page. Where can I start the check for this? I have shared a screenshot for the issue.

https://prnt.sc/cBSqTN5ee52t